# Python joining dictionary function?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, dictionary, nested

I have a random array of coordinates on top of which circles of radius k are plotted (ignore left/right keys for the moment)

```
cluster={"discs":set([i,j]),
         "left":x[i]<k or x[j]<k,
         "right":x[i]>(1-k) or x[j]>(1-k)}

for some_cluster in cluster:
    some_discs_set = some_cluster['discs']
    for some_other_cluster in cluster:
        some_other_discs_set = some_other_cluster['discs']
        if some_cluster is some_other_cluster:
            continue
        discs_in_both_sets = set(some_discs_set).intersection(set(some_other_discs_set))

    if len(discs_in_both_sets) != 0: #merge l/r boundaries
        some_cluster['discs'] = some_discs_set.union(some_other_discs_set)
        some_other_cluster['discs'] = {}

filtered_cluster = filter(lambda x: len(x['discs']), cluster)
```

I've noticed that although this code works for almost all the time, there are some times which three discs overlap and a fourth overlaps with only one of those three, and the dictionary only shows up as having three discs and not four. What am I missing? I think it has to be due to some of the iteration missing out certain discs but I'm not sure.

Using Python 2.7.3

Thx

Comment: The code you show only creates a single `cluster` dictionary, not a collection of them. Does your real code create a list of these dicts, or something? Where do the `i` and `j` values come from? Try to make a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

if you want do this

```
for some_cluster in cluster:
```

you need that cluster is a list of dictonary...